# Few questions from a Java programmer regarding porting preexisting database which is stored in .txt file to mySQL?

Tags: sql, mysql, jdbc

I've been writing a Library management Java app lately, and, up until now, the main Library database is stored in a `.txt` file which was later converted to `ArrayList` in Java for creating and editing the database and saving the alterations back to the `.txt` file again. A very primitive method indeed. Hence, having heard on SQL later on, I'm considering to port my preexisting `.txt` database to mySQL. Since I've absolutely no idea how SQL and specifically mySQL works, except for the fact that it can interact with Java code. Can you suggest me any books/websites to visit/buy? Will the book Head First with SQL ever help? especially when using Java code to interact with the SQL database? It should be mentioned that I'm already comfortable with using 3rd Party APIs.

Comment: Java: Use JDBC to connect to a MySQL db: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1640910/connecting-to-a-mysql-database

Comment: Your main hurdle to overcome will be SQL - data modelling and querying.

Comment: Excellent intro to SQL JOINs: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000976.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**View from 30,000 feet:**

First, you'll need to figure out how to represent the text file data using the appropriate SQL tables and fields.  [Here is a good overview](http://www.htmlite.com/mysql003.php) of the different SQL data types.  If your data represents a single Library record, then you'll only need to create 1 table.  This is definitely the simplest way to do it, as conversion will be able to work line-by-line.  If the records contain a LOT of data duplication, the most appropriate approach is to create multiple tables so that your database doesn't duplicate data.  You would then link these tables together using IDs.

When you've decided how to split up the data, you create a MySQL database, and within that database, you create the tables (a database is just something that holds multiple tables).  Connecting to your MySQL server with the console and creating a database and tables [is described in this MySQL tutorial](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/tutorial.html).

Once you've got the database created, you'll need to write the code to access the database.  [The link from OMG Ponies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1640910/connecting-to-a-mysql-database) shows how to use JDBC in the simplest way to connect to your database.  You then use that connection to create `Statement` object, execute a query to insert, update, select or delete data.  If you're selecting data, you get a `ResultSet` back and can view the data.  [Here's a tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/jdbc/overview/index.html) for using JDBC to select and use data from a `ResultSet`.

Your first code should probably be a Java utility that reads the text file and inserts all the data into the database.  Once you have the data in place, you'll be able to update the main program to read from the database instead of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Know that the connection between a program and a SQL database is through a 'connection program'. You write an instruction in an SQL statement, say

```
 Select * from Customer order by name;
```

and then set up to retrieve data one record at a time. Or in the other direction, you write

```
Insert into Customer (name, addr, ...) values (x, y, ...);
```

and either replace x, y, ... with actual values or bind them to the connection according to the interface.

With this understanding you should be able to read pretty much any book or JDBC API description and get started.