# Connect Java to a MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

How do you connect to a MySQL database in Java?

When I try, I get

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://database/table
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
```

Or

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Or

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

Comment: Here's a short 3-minute video tutorial that demonstrates using MySQL from Java. Check it out here: [Quick Tutorial: Connecting to MySQL database using Java](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3KT0haOSTEg)

Answer (score 232, accepted):

### `DataSource`

`DriverManager` is a fairly old way of doing things. The better way is to get a [`DataSource`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.sql/javax/sql/DataSource.html) object. Either by using [JNDI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Naming_and_Directory_Interface) to look one up that your app server container already configured for you:

```
Context context = new InitialContext();
DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) context.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/myDB");
```

… or by instantiating and configuring one from your database driver directly, such as `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlDataSource` ([see documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html)):

```
MysqlDataSource dataSource = new MysqlDataSource();
dataSource.setUser("scott");
dataSource.setPassword("tiger");
dataSource.setServerName("myDBHost.example.org");
```

… and then obtain connections from it, same as above:

```
Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection();
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT ID FROM USERS");
…
rs.close();
stmt.close();
conn.close();
```

In modern Java, use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) syntax to automatically close JDBC resources (now [`AutoCloseable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html)).

```java
try (
    Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection();
    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT ID FROM USERS");
) {
    …
}
```

Comment: how come the other examples use `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`? is this method better?

Comment: I think this is the old-style Driver class that works with the old-style driver mechanism. `MysqlDataSource` implements `javax.sql.DataSource` which is the newer mechanism.

Comment: @SeanOwen +1 for Good explanation. I was not aware of this method, because most of the people talk about DriverManager.

Comment: Hi @SeanOwen I wonder that, why do we close `rs` and `stmt`? Why not just `conn`?

Comment: Maybe you should add dataSource.setDatabaseName("database").

Comment: @SeanOwen Yes: Why do we need to close both of them ?

Comment: It's good practice to close() things explicitly, though it is more code. Any good implementation would have to close the resources when the connection closes, yes. Consider other contexts where you want to reuse a statement or connection though. In Java 7's try-with-resources, you get this behavior for free anyway:

Comment: How do I configure the context: `java:comp/env/jdbc/myDB` and where can it be found/configured?

Comment: There is a good tutorial here: http://www.journaldev.com/2509/java-datasource-jdbc-datasource-example

Comment: According to the [Java API specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#close), you do not need to close `ResultSet` objects: "When a `Statement` object is closed, its current `ResultSet` object, if one exists, is also closed."

Comment: Perhaps this example should be updated to use PreparedStatements instead, as they're generally preferable for security reasons? Or should it be left alone for simplicity's sake?

Comment: I think PreparedStatement is orthogonal - point here is connecting to the DB.

Comment: @GéryOgam In the past there were some notorious cases of JDBC drivers that failed to properly cascade the closing of such JDBC objects — thereby violating the requirements of the JDBC specification. These crucial flaws taught us to make a practice of explicitly closing each and every individual JDBC resource. This is now trivially easy to do: In modern Java, JDBC resources implement `AutoCloseable`, so we can use very simple try-with-resources syntax to automatically close.

Answer (score 540):

Here's a step by step explanation how to install MySQL and JDBC and how to use it:

1. **[Download](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/) and install the MySQL server**. Just do it the usual way. Remember the port number whenever you've changed it. It's by default `3306`.
2. **[Download](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) the JDBC driver and put in classpath**, extract the ZIP file and put the containing JAR file in the classpath. The vendor-specific JDBC driver is a concrete implementation of the [JDBC API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/package-summary.html) ([tutorial here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/index.html)).

   If you're using an IDE like Eclipse or Netbeans, then you can add it to the classpath by adding the JAR file as *Library* to the *Build Path* in project's properties.

   If you're doing it "plain vanilla" in the command console, then you need to specify the path to the JAR file in the `-cp` or `-classpath` argument when executing your Java application.

   ```
   java -cp .;/path/to/mysql-connector.jar com.example.YourClass
   ```

   The `.` is just there to add the *current* directory to the classpath as well so that it can locate `com.example.YourClass` and the `;` is the classpath separator as it is in Windows. In Unix and clones `:` should be used.

   If you're developing a servlet based WAR application and wish to manually manage connections (poor practice, actually), then you need to ensure that the JAR ends up in `/WEB-INF/lib` of the build. See also [How to add JAR libraries to WAR project without facing java.lang.ClassNotFoundException? Classpath vs Build Path vs /WEB-INF/lib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6792197/how-to-add-jar-libraries-to-war-project-without-facing-java-lang-classnotfoundex/6792774#6792774). The better practice is to install the physical JDBC driver JAR file in the server itself and configure the server to create a JDBC connection pool. Here's an example for Tomcat: [How should I connect to JDBC database / datasource in a servlet based application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2299469/how-should-i-connect-to-jdbc-database-datasource-in-a-servlet-based-applicatio/2299870#2299870)
3. **Create a [database](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.2/en/create-database.html) in MySQL**. Let's create a database `javabase`. You of course want World Domination, so let's use UTF-8 as well.

   ```
    CREATE DATABASE javabase DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
   ```
4. **[Create a user](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.2/en/create-user.html) for Java and [grant](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.2/en/grant.html) it access**. Simply because using `root` is a bad practice.

   ```
    CREATE USER 'java'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
    GRANT ALL ON javabase.* TO 'java'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
   ```

   Yes, `java` is the username and `password` is the password here.
5. **[Determine](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html) the JDBC URL**. To connect the MySQL database using Java you need an JDBC URL in the following syntax:

   ```
   jdbc:mysql://hostname:port/databasename
   ```

   - **`hostname`**: The hostname where MySQL server is installed. If it's installed at the same machine where you run the Java code, then you can just use `localhost`. It can also be an IP address like `127.0.0.1`. If you encounter connectivity problems and using `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` solved it, then you've a problem in your network/DNS/hosts config.
   - **`port`**: The TCP/IP port where MySQL server listens on. This is by default `3306`.
   - **`databasename`**: The name of the database you'd like to connect to. That's `javabase`.

   So the final URL should look like:

   ```
   jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/javabase
   ```
6. **[Test the connection](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-usagenotes-basic.html) to MySQL using Java**. Create a simple Java class with a `main()` method to test the connection.

   ```java
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/javabase";
    String username = "java";
    String password = "password";

    System.out.println("Connecting database ...");

    try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password)) {
        System.out.println("Database connected!");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot connect the database!", e);
    }
   ```

   If you get a `SQLException: No suitable driver`, then it means that either the JDBC driver wasn't autoloaded at all or that the JDBC URL is wrong (i.e. it wasn't recognized by any of the loaded drivers). See also [The infamous java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911253/the-infamous-java-sql-sqlexception-no-suitable-driver-found/1911487#1911487). Normally, a JDBC 4.0 driver should be autoloaded when you just drop it in runtime classpath. To exclude one and other, you can always manually load it as below:

   ```java
    System.out.println("Loading driver ...");

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"); // Use com.mysql.jdbc.Driver if you're not on MySQL 8+ yet.
        System.out.println("Driver loaded!");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot find the driver in the classpath!", e);
    }
   ```

   Note that the `newInstance()` call is **not** needed here. It's in case of MySQL just to fix the old and buggy `org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver`. [Explanation here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092659/what-is-difference-between-class-forname-and-class-forname-newinstance/2093236#2093236). If this line throws `ClassNotFoundException`, then the JAR file containing the JDBC driver class is simply not been placed in the classpath. Please also note that it's very important to throw an exception so that the code execution is immediately blocked, instead of suppressing it of merely printing the stack trace and then continuing the rest of the code.

   Also note that you don't need to load the driver **everytime** *before* connecting. Just only once during application startup is enough.

   If you get a `SQLException: Connection refused` or `Connection timed out` or a MySQL specific `CommunicationsException:  Communications link failure`, then it means that the DB isn't reachable at all. This can have one or more of the following causes:

   1. IP address or hostname in JDBC URL is wrong.
   2. Hostname in JDBC URL is not recognized by local DNS server.
   3. Port number is missing or wrong in JDBC URL.
   4. DB server is down.
   5. DB server doesn't accept TCP/IP connections.
   6. DB server has run out of connections.
   7. Something in between Java and DB is blocking connections, e.g. a firewall or proxy.

   To solve the one or the other, follow the following advices:

   1. Verify and test them with `ping`.
   2. Refresh DNS or use IP address in JDBC URL instead.
   3. Verify it based on `my.cnf` of MySQL DB.
   4. Start the DB.
   5. Verify if mysqld is started without the `--skip-networking option`.
   6. Restart the DB and fix your code accordingly that it closes connections in `finally`.
   7. Disable firewall and/or configure firewall/proxy to allow/forward the port.

   Note that closing the `Connection` is **extremely** important. If you don't close connections and keep getting a lot of them in a short time, then the database may run out of connections and your application may break. Always acquire the `Connection` in a [`try-with-resources` statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html). This also applies to `Statement`, `PreparedStatement` and `ResultSet`. See also [How often should Connection, Statement and ResultSet be closed in JDBC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5602772/how-often-should-connection-statement-and-resultset-be-closed-in-jdbc/5602821#5602821)

That was it as far the connectivity concerns. You can find [here](https://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/07/dao-tutorial-data-layer.html) a more advanced tutorial how to load and store fullworthy Java model objects in a database with help of a basic DAO class.

---

Using a Singleton Pattern and/or a `static` variable for the DB `Connection` is a **bad practice**. See among others [Is it safe to use a static java.sql.Connection instance in a multithreaded system?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9428573/) This is a #1 starters mistake. Make sure you don't fall in this trap.

Comment: I was getting the same error. Updating the driver version worked for me. https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/c-j/

Comment: What should be the hostname and port value in JDBC url, if connecting to a MySQL docker container (using a docker-compose.yaml)? Is it still `localhost` or `172.17.0.1` (docker0) or the mysql service name?

Comment: @marc: hostname is indeed the docker service name (the key of `services` object). Port is the second value you've specified in ports config. If it's `3306:3306` then it's still `3306`.

Comment: @BalusC : I got rid of the connection refused error by changing database.driver value from `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` to `com.mysql.jdbc.driver`. However, does it really because of the capital letter? I just want to make sure, thank you

Answer (score 49):

### Initialize database constants

Create constant properties database username, password, URL and drivers, polling limit etc.

```
// init database constants
// com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
private static final String DATABASE_DRIVER = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver";
private static final String DATABASE_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database_name";
private static final String USERNAME = "root";
private static final String PASSWORD = "";
private static final String MAX_POOL = "250"; // set your own limit
```

### Initialize Connection and Properties

Once the connection is established, it is better to store for reuse purpose.

```
// init connection object
private Connection connection;
// init properties object
private Properties properties;
```

### Create Properties

The properties object hold the connection information, check if it is already set.

```
// create properties
private Properties getProperties() {
    if (properties == null) {
        properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("user", USERNAME);
        properties.setProperty("password", PASSWORD);
        properties.setProperty("MaxPooledStatements", MAX_POOL);
    }
    return properties;
}
```

### Connect the Database

Now connect to database using the constants and properties initialized.

```
// connect database
public Connection connect() {
    if (connection == null) {
        try {
            Class.forName(DATABASE_DRIVER);
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DATABASE_URL, getProperties());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            // Java 7+
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return connection;
}
```

### Disconnect the database

Once you are done with database operations, just close the connection.

```
// disconnect database
public void disconnect() {
    if (connection != null) {
        try {
            connection.close();
            connection = null;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

### Everything together

Use this class `MysqlConnect` directly after changing database_name, username and password etc.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Properties;

public class MysqlConnect {
    // init database constants
    private static final String DATABASE_DRIVER = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver";
    private static final String DATABASE_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database_name";
    private static final String USERNAME = "root";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "";
    private static final String MAX_POOL = "250";

    // init connection object
    private Connection connection;
    // init properties object
    private Properties properties;

    // create properties
    private Properties getProperties() {
        if (properties == null) {
            properties = new Properties();
            properties.setProperty("user", USERNAME);
            properties.setProperty("password", PASSWORD);
            properties.setProperty("MaxPooledStatements", MAX_POOL);
        }
        return properties;
    }

    // connect database
    public Connection connect() {
        if (connection == null) {
            try {
                Class.forName(DATABASE_DRIVER);
                connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DATABASE_URL, getProperties());
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return connection;
    }

    // disconnect database
    public void disconnect() {
        if (connection != null) {
            try {
                connection.close();
                connection = null;
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### How to Use?

Initialize the database class.

```
// !_ note _! this is just init
// it will not create a connection
MysqlConnect mysqlConnect = new MysqlConnect();
```

Somewhere else in your code ...

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM `stackoverflow`";
try {
    PreparedStatement statement = mysqlConnect.connect().prepareStatement(sql);
    ... go on ...
    ... go on ...
    ... DONE ....
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    mysqlConnect.disconnect();
}
```

This is all **:)** If anything to improve edit it! Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Mark, does each class need to maintain it's own separate MysqlConnect instance open at all times - assuming they need to interact wit the data? I'm just wondering how this setup works between classes.

Comment: in place of ```com.mysql.jdbc.Driver``` this ```jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/stocks``` should be used as the former is deprecated.

Comment: If you are going to hardwire account name, password, database name etc, this way is very clumsy.  Just put all of those details into the JDBC URL string.  (Including the pool size ...)

Comment: I would suggest using a [`DataSource`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.sql/javax/sql/DataSource.html) implementation rather than these hard-coded properties. Ex: `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlDataSource`.  See [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html).

Comment: I would suggest using a [`DataSource`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.sql/javax/sql/DataSource.html) implementation rather than these hard-coded properties. Ex: `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlDataSource`.  See [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html). See [Answer by Sean Oven](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2839563/642706).

Answer (score 27):

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/yourdatabase";
String user = "username";
String password = "password";

// Load the Connector/J driver
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
// Establish connection to MySQL
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
```

Comment: what is yourdatabase in here? database name?

Comment: *newInstance()* is not necessary. Is it?

Comment: Nope.  It isn't.  And since Java 6 this whole approach is out of date.  And the driver class name has changed and ....

Comment: What is interesting is that in the doc for DriverManager https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html it is stated that no longer Class.forName() is needed but instead some properties file java.sql.Driver could be used

Comment: database name here seems to be "yourdatabase" as you can see in the url

Answer (score 13):

Here's the very minimum you need to get data out of a MySQL database:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection
   ("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/foo", "root", "password");

Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
stmt.execute("SELECT * FROM `FOO.BAR`");
stmt.close();
conn.close();
```

Add exception handling, configuration etc. to taste.

Comment: why do you need `Class.forName(...).newInstance()`?

Comment: @mmcrae You don't, since 2007.

Answer (score 3):

you need to have mysql connector jar in your classpath.

in Java JDBC API makes everything with databases. using JDBC  we can write Java applications to
1. Send queries or  update SQL to DB(any relational Database) 
2. Retrieve and process the results from DB

with below three steps we can able to retrieve data from any  Database

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                     "jdbc:myDriver:DatabaseName",
                     dBuserName,
                     dBuserPassword);

Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT a, b, c FROM Table");

while (rs.next()) {
    int x = rs.getInt("a");
    String s = rs.getString("b");
    float f = rs.getFloat("c");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can see all steps to connect MySQL database from Java application [here](http://apekshit.com/t/51/Steps-to-connect-Database-using-JAVA). For other database, you just need to change the driver in first step only. Please make sure that you provide right path to database and correct username and password.

Visit http://apekshit.com/t/51/Steps-to-connect-Database-using-JAVA

Answer (score 2):

Short and Sweet code.

```java
try {       
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    System.out.println("Driver Loaded");
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testDB","root","");
    //Database Name - testDB, Username - "root", Password - ""
    System.out.println("Connected...");         
} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

For SQL server 2012

```java
try {
    String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://KHILAN:1433;databaseName=testDB;user=Khilan;password=Tuxedo123"; 
    //KHILAN is Host    and 1433 is port number     
    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
    System.out.println("Driver Loaded");
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
    System.out.println("Connected...");
} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

MySQL JDBC Connection with useSSL.

```
private String db_server = BaseMethods.getSystemData("db_server");
private String db_user = BaseMethods.getSystemData("db_user");
private String db_password = BaseMethods.getSystemData("db_password");

private String connectToDb() throws Exception {
   String jdbcDriver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
   String dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql://" + db_server  +
        "?verifyServerCertificate=false" +
        "&useSSL=true" +
        "&requireSSL=true";
    System.setProperty(jdbcDriver, "");
    Class.forName(jdbcDriver).newInstance();

    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, db_user, db_password);
    Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
    String query = "SELECT EXTERNAL_ID FROM offer_letter where ID =" + "\"" + letterID + "\"";
    ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);
    resultSet.next();
    return resultSet.getString(1);
}
```

Comment: The way the query string is created is an example of a very bad practice that is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 1):

`Connection` I was using some time ago, it was looking like the easiest way, but also there were recommendation to make there `if` statement- exactly

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                     "jdbc:myDriver:DatabaseName",
                     dBuserName,
                     dBuserPassword);
if (con != null){
 //..handle your code there 
}
```

Or something like in that way :)

Probably there's some case, while `getConnection` can return `null`  :)

Answer (score 1):

HOW

- To set up the Driver to run a quick sample

```
1. Go to https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/, get the latest version of Connector/J

2. Remember to set the classpath to include the path of the connector jar file.
If we don't set it correctly, below errors can occur:

No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/msystem_development

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc:Driver
```

- To set up the CLASSPATH

Method 1: set the CLASSPATH variable.

```
export CLASSPATH=".:mysql-connector-java-VERSION.jar"
java MyClassFile
```

In the above command, I have set the CLASSPATH to the current folder and mysql-connector-java-VERSION.jar file. So when the `java MyClassFile` command executed, java application launcher will try to load all the Java class in CLASSPATH.
And it found the `Drive` class => BOOM errors was gone.

Method 2:

```
java -cp .:mysql-connector-java-VERSION.jar MyClassFile
```

*Note: Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); This is deprecated at this moment 2019 Apr.*

Hope this can help someone!

Answer (score -1):

MySql JDBC Connection:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");     

Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DatabaseName","Username","Password");         
Statement stmt=con.createStatement();            
stmt = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("Select * from Table");
```

Answer (score -1):

**Short Code**

```
public class DB {

    public static Connection c;

    public static Connection getConnection() throws Exception {
        if (c == null) {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            c =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DATABASE", "USERNAME", "Password");
        }
        return c;
    }

    // Send data TO Database
    public static void setData(String sql) throws Exception {
        DB.getConnection().createStatement().executeUpdate(sql);
    }

    // Get Data From Database
    public static ResultSet getData(String sql) throws Exception {
        ResultSet rs = DB.getConnection().createStatement().executeQuery(sql);
        return rs;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

**Download JDBC Driver**

Download link (Select platform independent): https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/

**Move JDBC Driver to C Drive**

Unzip the files and move to C:\ drive. Your driver path should be like `C:\mysql-connector-java-8.0.19\mysql-connector-java-8.0.19`

**Run Your Java**

```
java -cp "C:\mysql-connector-java-8.0.19\mysql-connector-java-8.0.19\mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar" testMySQL.java
```

testMySQL.java

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.io.*;

public class testMySQL {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try
        {  
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");  
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(  
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db?useSSL=false&useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC","root","");  
            Statement stmt=con.createStatement();  
            ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("show databases;");  
            System.out.println("Connected");  
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }  

}
```

[image]